# How can I set a cron job with yesterday's date in Solaris?

Tags: perl, date, unix, cron, solaris

I want to set a cron job with yesterday's date on a Unix server (Solaris). I tried:

```
TZ=CST+24 date +%Y%m%d
```

but got

```
had TZ=CST+24: not found
```

I tried

```
`perl -mPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%Y%m%d",localtime(time() - 86400)) '`
```

This works but I’m not sure that all the clients have Perl on their machines.

`date -v` and `date -d` don't work; only the `-u` and `-a` options work with date in Unix:

```
date: illegal option -- d
usage: date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
date [-u] [+format]
date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused exactly what you're trying to do. Since you couldn't possibly be trying to go back in time to run a cron job yesterday, you must be trying to print yesterday's date from a cron job running today. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

`cron` expects a command to run, not a line a shell can parse. You can run the shell as the command, though, and give it the line as the argument:

```
bash -c 'TZ=CST+24 date +%Y%m%d'
```

Specifying full path to `bash` might be needed, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep the lines in the cron easy to understand. Something like

```
5 * * * * /mypath/rotate.sh
```

The script should have the logic for making a variabele with the date.

You already found manipulating the Timezone for changing the clock some hours. An extra complexity is the Daylight Saving Time. Due to the daylight saving time, 24 hours ago can be today or the day before yesterday.

You are sure that yesterday is 20 or 30 hours ago. Which one? Well, the most recent one that is not today.

```
echo "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

Above command is for ksh. When you use bash, you want echo -e:

```
echo -e "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```